# Tire does not find partial word (search on 2 fields)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, tire

What I want to do:

- I have a model 'Item' with 2 fields I want elasticsearch to search on: title and description.
- I want the search to find partial words, ex: bicycl should match against bicycle, bicycles, etc...

Current situation:

- The search only shows perfect matches

Here is what I have right now in my Item model:

```
 include Tire::Model::Search
 include Tire::Model::Callbacks

 class << self
   def search_index
     Tire.index(Item.index_name)
   end
 end

 settings :analysis => {
                    :filter => {
                      :my_ngram  => {
                        "type"     => "nGram",
                        "max_gram" => 10,
                        "min_gram" => 3 }
                    },
                    :analyzer => {
                      :my_analyzer => {
                         "type"         => "custom",
                         "tokenizer"    => "standard",
                         "filter"       => ["my_ngram"]
                       }
                    }
                  } do
   mapping do
     indexes :title,       boost: 10, analyzer: 'my_analyzer'
     indexes :description, boost: 5,  analyzer: 'my_analyzer'
   end
end

 def self.search(query_string)
   tire.search(load: true) do
     if query_string.present?
       query do
         string query_string, default_operator: "AND"
       end
     end
   end
 end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do...

```
string query_string, default_operator: "AND"
```

... you're actually searching the magic `_all` field.

I'm pretty sure that you need to specifically search for the field analyzed with the ngram filter for this to work.

```
should { string "title:#{query_string}", default_operator: "OR" }
should { string "description:#{query_string}", default_operator: "OR" }
```

for instance.